# Draw KML Extent Given an XML in ArcGIS JS SDK

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, kml

I have a link that will return an HTML with the plain text of an XML. An example is below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<Style id="0"> 
</Style> 
<Placemark>
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-85.168000000000006,30.344000000000001 -83.069000000000003,25.523 -52.729999999999997,30.094000000000001 -53.235999999999997,35.152000000000001 -85.168000000000006,30.344000000000001</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I need to be able to create a KML that is described above I have tried the code below but to no avail. There were other attempts, but I do not remember exactly what I changed as this was last week.

```
let kmlExtent = null;
    function drawKML(dataid) {
        let kURL = "https://.../cwn_L2_kml.cgi?dataid=" + dataid;
        
        if (kmlExtent == null) {
            console.log("here");
            actDrawKML(kURL);
        } else if (kmlExtent != null) {
            console.log("here2")
            map.remove(kmlExtent);
            actDrawKML(kURL);
        }
    }
    function actDrawKML(kURL) {
        fetch(proxyUrl + kURL)
        .then(response => response.blob()) // Parse the JSON response
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.type);
            // Create a Blob with the KML content and correct MIME type
            const kmlBlob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml'});
            const kmlUrl = URL.createObjectURL(kmlBlob);
            kmlExtent = new KMLLayer({
                visible: true,
                url: kmlUrl,
                title: "Spatial Extent"
            });
            map.add(kmlExtent);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching or processing KML content: ', error));
    }
```

The console outputs are in the image below. I don't know what else I could try I tried parsing it as a JSON with `response.JSON()`, but that did not work. Is there any suggestions on what to try?
[image: Console statements]

```
error: k {name: 'request:server', details: {…}, message: 'Unable to load https://utility.arcgis.com/sharing/…Dsl7F9KurI89k2tGEKbfrfdpoX6ek8Kh0rqIf status: 400'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are out of luck here with using object URL for `url` option when creating KML layer. If you look at the docs at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-KMLLayer.html#url, you can read:

> The publicly accessible URL for a .kml or .kmz file.

This means you can't use object URL for KML layer `url` option.

If you don't explictly want to add KML layer, one possible solution is to convert KML to GeoJSON and then add GeoJSON layer. Conversion can be done with Mapbox [togeojson](https://github.com/mapbox/togeojson) JS library.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
fetch(kmlUrl)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xml = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
    const geojson = toGeoJSON.kml(xml);
    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(geojson)], {
      type: "application/json"
    });
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const layer = new GeoJSONLayer({
      url
    });
    groupLayer.add(layer);
  });
```

This is the result:

[image]